# Does chunk (0,0) have an increased spawn rate as claimed in this old post?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/alpha/alpha-survival-single-player/820173-mob-spawning-science

The above given link looks old. But the section: 4 given in it looks interesting.

It States,

> The chunk traversal order is unique for every chunk the player is in,
>   but there is one exception. If the chunk (0,0) (blocks 0,0 to 15,15)
>   is one of the 81 chunks visited, it will always be the first
>   evaluated. This can be exploited. Regardless of the terrain, there is
>   a 100% chance the algorithm will not bail out before getting to this
>   chunk. This means that chunk (0,0) has the highest chance of spawning
>   mobs than any of the other 8 chunks. It's as high as CleanRoom.
>
> To illustrate this, I built a 19x19x64 tower over chunk (0,0) with 16
>   spawning floors. After a couple of minutes there were about 150 mobs
>   in the tower, and there probably would have been more if the cap
>   hadn't been reached. (glass was hacked in with NBTForge for your
>   viewing convenience. Original walls were rock.)
>
> This technique should work on any map, and if I'm not mistaken, SMP,
>   too (as of yet unverified).

I don't know if this exists for minecraft 1.9, this is fixed, or maybe it is not vanilla.

**Is it true for minecraft 1.9?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No

I ran a simple test in a void world. I built two sets of spawning platforms with 12 levels each: One in chunk (0,0), the other in (0,-2).

I then ran a couple of command blocks to count mob spawns on each platform, using `/tp` rather than `/kill` to prevent mob drops:

```
/tp @e[x=0,y=0,z=0,dx=15,dy=255,dz=15,type=!Player] ~ ~-64 ~
/tp @e[x=0,y=0,z=-32,dx=15,dy=255,dz=15,type=!Player] ~ ~-64 ~
```

Using `/stats block`, I stored `AffectedEntities` in an objective (`count`) on fake players `#Temp1` and `#Temp2`, which were then added to the running totals.

```
/scoreboard players operation Total1 count += #Temp1 count
/scoreboard players operation Total2 count += #Temp2 count
```

I ran a couple of runs, resetting the scores at the beginning of the experiment and clearing all mobs first. This screenshot was taken after the end of the first run.

[image: Screenshot of test run #1]

```
Run#   Time   Total1  Total2 
------------------------------
  1    4197    2623    2841     
  2    3200    2136    2013
  3    3702    2379    2223
  4    4205    2692    2679
```

There is no significant difference between the numbers to be seen, averaging out at 0.644±0.012 and 0.636±0.021 mob spawns per tick, respectively.